# Conflicts between libraries Glide/PhotoView/ZGallery

Tags: android, shared-libraries, android-glide, lib, android-photoview

I wrote an app in which I use Glide (4.7.1 version) and PhotoView (2.1.4). Today I add another library Zgallery (version 0.3.1). When I try to run my app part of Zgallery doesnt work. I saw that Zgallery use Glide and PhotoView too, but other versions (3.7.0 for Glide and 1.3.0 for PhotoView). To makes it right I downgrade my lib versions to this and now Zgallery part works but rest doesn't. It's obvious that this libs fight each other but why ? There is an option that my app will use actual versions and this Zgallery lib old versions ? Or maybe there is a chance to update this library from Android Studio ?

Comment: `:zgallery:0.3`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya ??

Comment: show your build.gradle

Comment: in my gradle build there is nothing fancy the point is that I can't go into lib gradle

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions of your problem.
Due to low backword compability of Glide, there could be different methods in different versions, so

***Solution one***: Make a fork of lib you need and update libs by yourself

***Solution two (ugly)***: keep both versions of libs in your app

***Solution tree***: Use Zgallery libs versions

Comment: Yea I tried solution two (simple one) but it doesn't work. Solution three won't work for rest code